# Provide full rw access to one table in MySQL database

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-grant

I need to give user rights to read a particular DB  tables and RW access to one of these.

I made commands such as

```
  GRANT SELECT ON database.* TO 'someuser'@'somehost';
 GRANT SELECT,INSERT,UPDATE,DELETE ON database.rwtable TO 'someuser'@'somehost';
```

But now I (using phpmyadmin) can access the database tables, but all tables, including the one I asked to have insert privileges, is read only.

Please suggest how to assign corret rights,
Askar

Answer (score 0):

[Table Privileges](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/grant.html)

Change your databasename.table according to your needs.

Table privileges apply to all columns in a given table. To assign table-level privileges, use ON db_name.tbl_name syntax:

```
GRANT ALL ON mydb.mytbl TO 'someuser'@'somehost';
GRANT SELECT,INSERT,UPDATE,DELETE ON mydb.mytbl TO 'someuser'@'somehost';
```